# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator empty when passed a RecursiveRegexIterator

Tags: php, regex, spl

A snapshot of **Explorer** class can be see below -

```
class Explorer
{
    //....

    public function getIterator()
    {
        //$iterator = new FileSearchIterator($this->baseDir, $this->pattern, $this->buildFlag());
        if ($this->iterator) {
            return $this->iterator;
        }

        $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->baseDir, $this->buildFlag());

        if ($this->ignoreVcsFiles) {
            $this->ignore = array_merge($this->ignore, static::$vcsFiles);
        }

        if (!empty($this->ignore)) {
            $iterator = new ExcludeFilter($iterator, $this->ignore);
        }

        if ($this->searchFor === static::SEARCH_FILES) {
            $iterator = new FilenameRegexFilter($iterator, $this->pattern);
        } else {
            $iterator = new DirectoryRegexFilter($iterator, $this->pattern);
        }

        $this->iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator);
        return $this->iterator;
    }

    //......
}
```

In Tests the given directory contains a single php file. But when filtering for only ****.php*** files using `new FilenameRegexFilter(...)` and then passing it through `RecursiveIteratorIterator` results in an empty `RecursiveIteratorIterator` instance.

You can see the rest of the filter classes (used above) below -

```
class ExcludeFilter extends \RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    protected $iterator;
    protected $ignore = [];

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function __construct(\RecursiveIterator $iterator, array $ignore)
    {
        $this->iterator = $iterator;
        $this->ignore = $ignore;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        return !in_array($this->current()->getFilename(), $this->ignore, true);
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        $children = parent::getChildren();
        $children->ignore = $this->ignore;

        return $children;
    }
}


class FilenameRegexFilter extends RecursiveRegexFilter
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function accept()
    {
        return ($this->current()->isFile() && preg_match($this->regex, $this->current()->getFilename()));
    }

    /**
     * @return \RecursiveRegexIterator
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        $children = parent::getChildren();
        $children->regex = $this->regex;
        return $children;
    }
}

abstract class RecursiveRegexFilter extends \RecursiveRegexIterator
{
    protected $regex;
    protected $iterator;

    /**
     * RegexFilter constructor.
     * @param \RecursiveIterator $iterator
     * @param string $regex
     */
    public function __construct(\RecursiveIterator $iterator, $regex)
    {
        $this->iterator = $iterator;
        $this->regex = $this->toRegex($regex);
        parent::__construct($iterator, $this->regex);
    }

    /**
     * @return \RecursiveRegexIterator
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        $children = new static($this->iterator->getChildren(), $this->regex);
        return $children;
    }

    /**
     * @param $pattern
     * @param array $options
     * @return string
     */
    public function toRegex($pattern, $options = [])
    {
        $pattern = str_replace(array('\*', '\?'), array('.*','.'), preg_quote($pattern));
        $pattern = '/^' . $pattern . '$/';
        if (!empty($options)) {
            $pattern .= implode('', $options);
        }

        return $pattern;
    }
}

class DirectoryRegexFilter extends RecursiveRegexFilter
{
    public function accept()
    {
        return ($this->current()->isDir() || preg_match($this->regex, $this->current()->getFilename()));
    }
}
```

I don't get where I'm going wrong. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:** To simplify my Question largely is how do I use RecursiveDirectoryIterator with RecursiveFilterIterator

Comment: One thing is certain: you need `preg_quote($pattern, "/")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm already doing a `preg_quote` in `public function toRegex($pattern, $options = [])`

Comment: You do not escape `/` there: `preg_quote($pattern)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks i'll fix that, any idea though what could be the problem here ... coz i still get a empty RecursiveIteratorIterator instance, and my test string is  "*.php"

Comment: Your question is too broad: please find the "culprit" block, and re-write the question to include an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okie to simplify .. how do I use RecursiveFilterIterator with RecursiveDirectoryIterator??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110845/discussion-between-shalomsam-and-wiktor-stribizew).